# Error installing package "lifecycle" (while trying to install ggplot 3.3.0, R 3.5.3)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `R: 3.5.3 on Windows`

I want to install `ggplot2` (current version 3.3.0). It seems that the package `ggplot2` needs another package `lifecycle`, which I cannot successfully install due to errors.
I've tried to install `ggplot2` with all dependencies and also tried to install `lifecycle` separately and always got the same error.

Here is the anonymized output (in German):

```
> install.packages("lifecycle", dependencies = FALSE)
Installing package into ‘USERID/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
lifecycle  0.1.0  0.2.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘lifecycle’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_0.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 164455 bytes (160 KB)
downloaded 160 KB

"USER PATH"
CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
UNC-Pfade werden nicht untersttzt.
Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** Paket 'lifecycle' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'lifecycle'
    finding HTML links ... fertig
    badge                                   html  
    deprecate_soft                          html  
    deprecated                              html  
    expect_deprecated                       html  
Rd warning: USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpecQ7zL/R.INSTALLd4014024cc2/lifecycle/man/expect_deprecated.Rd:17: file link 'expect_warning' in package 'testthat' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    last_warnings                           html  
    lifecycle-package                       html  
    signal_experimental                     html  
Rd warning: USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpecQ7zL/R.INSTALLd4014024cc2/lifecycle/man/signal_experimental.Rd:28: file link 'signal' in package 'rlang' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpecQ7zL/R.INSTALLd4014024cc2/lifecycle/man/signal_experimental.Rd:29: file link 'signalCondition' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    verbosity                               html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warnung in file(con, "w")
  kann Datei 'USERID/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle/doc/index.html' nicht öffnen: No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing 'USERID/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
```

as far as I understand, the `Rd warning` are not critically but then somehow the actual directory seems to be missing.

I also tried to download the binaries and copy the package `lifecycle` in my `R/win-library/3.5` but this leads to just another error

```
> library("lifecycle", lib.loc="‘USERID/R/win-library/3.5")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lifecycle’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Any ideas to resolve this or does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Sometimes R (esp on windows) needs to be restarted with a clean environment. Can you restart R (no `.Rdata` reloading) and try again? I don't know that this'll do anything differently, but I see nothing obvious in your output above.

Comment: @r2evans I've just ``file.remove(".RData")`` and restarted ``R``. Unfortunately I got the exact same error...good idea though, haven't tried that before.

Comment: As a first step, you should update R. 3.5.3 is quite old.

Comment: @Roland Unfortunately I am not maintaining our R distribution (don't have the permissions). But I will write a ticket for our IT team...do you think this is related to the older state of the R version? I asked a colleague who is using ggplot2 (3.0.0) (uses the same R version) without even having installed ``lifecycle`` ...

Comment: The issue might resolve itself if you give it a day or two. The newest version of lifecycle has just been released and apparently the binary is not available on all mirrors yet.